# Selenium C# automation test Asserting file has been downloaded on azure devops release

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, automation, ui-automation

I'm currently running my automation tests locally on a computer.
I'm thinking about publishing them onto azure devops & run all the tests there.
On one of my tests I declared where to file should be downloaded, checked & deleted afterwards. While it works while Im running the test locally via visual studio But when the test runs in Azure Im getting **System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Downloads'.**
What seems to be the problem?
Thanks. My code below

```
var filedownload = driver.FindElement(WebObjects.downloadThefile);
            Assert.IsTrue(downloadThefile.Enabled);
            downloadThefile.Click();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

            int fileIsDownloaded = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Downloads\", "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
            if (fileIsDownloaded > 0)
            {
               Assert.IsTrue(fileIsDownloaded > 0);
            }
            else
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(fileIsDownloaded < 0);
            }
            string[] downloadedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Downloads\", "*.pdf");
            foreach (string file in downloadedFiles)
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to run a test that asserts & verifies that certain file has been downloaded?

This feature should be written in the repository instead of Azure DevOps, In your description, you have done this. You could feel free to run the test in the Azure DevOps and it should be work. You could refer to this [blog](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/selenium/) to create Selenium test pipeline in the Azure DevOps.

Comment: Yup. I've written the test on visual studio/pushed and setup up my CI/CD pipelines. But whenever I run the test I get System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path. I updated my question with code that Im running.

Comment: Run the pipeline via self-hosted agent instead of Hosted agent, Hosted agent cannot access your local machine. Check this [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to set it up the download path as
`int fileIsDownloaded = Directory.GetFiles(AppContext.BaseDirectory,"*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;`